# SQL | Find records with similar column string?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database of thousands of strings. I want to be able to select records that have a matching column string of a certain percentage specified.

For instance:

```
ID | Description
----------------
0  | This is a description
1  | This is a description
2  | This is also description
3  | How's it going
4  | Hows it going
```

With a required percentage match of 60% and greater, the following would occur:

`"This is a description"` returns:

```
row 1 (100% match)
row 2 (100% match)
row 3 (85% match, more or less)
```

`"How is it going"` returns:

```
row 3 (85% match, more or less)
row 4 (75% match, more or less)
```

I don't have a strict way of determing the percentage mach. I think that will depend on the options that SQL has available.

Comment: MySQL doesn't have anything built in that's useful for this. You can define a Levenshtein function, see https://lucidar.me/en/web-dev/levenshtein-distance-in-mysql/ for an example.

Comment: Interesting. What would the performance look like on a large table of tens of thousands of records?

Comment: It would be horrible, since it has to compare every record, indexes are not helpful.

Comment: I need to find a more efficient method

Comment: I would be okay with having less accurate results if necessary

Comment: @Barmar Let me ask you this. Do you think it would make more sense to use a more general comparison to narrow down the results, then return the results to the client and use a fuzzy search there?

Comment: Maybe consider full text index

Comment: BTW, you're confusing rows and columns.